# PHP Load Monitoring - "cat /proc/loadavg: No Such File" error

Tags: linux, shell, load, monitoring

hope you can help with this I'm trying to use this script to monitor a servers load and email me if it spikes over 4, it's setup in cron to run every five minutes but I get the error "cat /proc/loadavg: No Such File or directory", I've checked and can access proc from the command line and it is mounted so I'm not sure what the problem is. The script is in /home/user/ directory.

Thanks in advance.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    trigger=4.00
    load=`cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'`
    response=`echo | awk -v T=$trigger -v L=$load 'BEGIN{if ( L > T){ print "greater"}}'`
    if [[ $response = "greater" ]]
    then
    sar -q | mail -s"High load on server - [ $load ]" me@domain.com
    fi
```

Comment: try load=`cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'` to load=$(cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}')

Answer (score 0):

It could be a path issue.

Add a "echo $PATH >somefile" to see your path.  Then make sure that path works for all commands (sar, cat, awk, mail).

If not, either set the PATH in your script or fully qualify the location of the commands